# Android: Same response in Toast for async task onpostexecute()

Tags: android, web-services, toast

I am deling with web services and I got a problem with my Toast in onpostexecute() method. I am trying to show the toast according to the logcat response.resultsRequestSOAP is a string value I am retrieving from server. If the string value is 1 then I should show "registerd" in toast. If 0 then "Try again" and If -1 then "Field is empty"

In my logcat I m getting the response as string value.

The problem is every time I am getting "Try again" toast message.

The problem might be with Boolean(which I m using) instead of primitive value which never returns null. I m confused with this line  else if (resultsRequestSOAP.booleanValue()). its not working for me. how to solve this?

plz some one check the code in onpostexecute() and let me know the problem.

I want to compare the value in logcatand show the toast like this.
 If its 1 then "Registered", 
  If its 0 then "Try again",
 If its -1 then "field should not be empty"

Help is always appreciated...!

```
    public class Register extends Activity {

       public static final  Boolean resultsRequestSOAP = null;

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

 private class RegisterTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
      private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);

      protected void onPreExecute() {
         this.dialog.setMessage("Registering...");
         this.dialog.show();


 public Boolean register() {

  // code for webservices********  
     }

 return resultsRequestSOAP;

protected void onPostExecute( Boolean resultsRequestSOAP) {
         if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
         }
         if (resultsRequestSOAP == null) {
             Toast.makeText(Register.this.getApplicationContext(), "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

         else if (resultsRequestSOAP.booleanValue()) {
         //also show register success dialog
             Toast.makeText(Register.this.getApplicationContext(), "Registerd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


         }
         else{
             Toast.makeText(Register.this.getBaseContext(), "Field is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
         super.onPostExecute(resultsRequestSOAP);
      }
```

Comment: did you try using only this in Toast

Comment: @Rasel, yes tried  only with toast

Comment: did you put AsynchTask class as a inner class"

Comment: yes its inner class, you want me to post the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        protected void onPostExecute( Boolean resultsRequestSOAP) {
                 if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                    this.dialog.dismiss();
                 }
                 sendResult(resultsRequestSoap);
super.onPostExecute(resultsRequestSOAP);


    }
```

put this method on outer class

```
public void sendResult(String resultsRequestSoap){
if (resultsRequestSOAP == null) {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

             else if (resultsRequestSOAP.booleanValue()) {
             //also show register success dialog
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Registerd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


             }
             else{
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Field is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }


}
```

Comment: @Rasel, Thanks but I m not getting the result. its showing the "tryagain" every time

Comment: resultsRequestSOAP is always null.check the value where it is supposed to change

Comment: @Rasel,Thanks for ur valuable suggestion. I got some problem here. I am getting logcat response as a string value but here in my code I m checking for boolean, im confused with this issue.                                        else if (resultsRequestSOAP.booleanValue()) {
             //also show register success dialog
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Registerd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


             }
is the line where I should check but I dont know how to do this

Comment: where you change resultsRequestSOAP

Comment: @Rasel , why do you need to return a Boolean and not boolean (primitive type, which can't be null)? some one asked me this question earlier. and I tried to modify above line which I have shown . As I m new to android I couldn't resolve this. could u help in this?

Comment: if logcat shows the response as 1   i want to show the toast"Registered" except this there is no issue.

Comment: boolean is a primitive type which is true or false.On the otherhand Boolean is wrapper class like Integer,